# Post from Facebook Games not showing on my feed

Tags: facebook, status

I have my wife as a friend on Facebook, She sends me game requests on Facebook but I do not receive them at all. We both have checked our settings thoroughly. All the other Friends and Family of ours' are receiving the Game Requests. I am able to see her other activities - it's just the Game requests of a particular game that never show up. I have contacted Zynga and they said that it must be a FB problem.

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: And you have not blocked Pioneer Trail or your wife's updates?

Answer (score 1):

You may have blocked that particular game/App. Unblock it here: https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=121070141307903

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of possibilities:

1. You have blocked Game Requests from your wife.
2. You have blocked the particular game in question.
3. You have blocked notifications/invites from the particular game in question.
4. You do not have your wife added in your friend list.